# Rails - after_update :reload_page does not refresh the page when record in the database was updated

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Here is my controller (ClientController):

```
class ClientController < ApplicationController
  layout 'application'

  before_filter :client_selected, :only => [ :index,:show]
  after_filter  :reload_page, :only => :update

  def reload_page
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html {redirect_to :controller=>"client", :action=>"show", :layout => 'application'}
      format.js {render inline: "location.reload();" }
    end

    def index
    end

    def show
    end
  end
```

Don't know what I am missing here?

Comment: you have `index` and `show` actions _inside_ reload_page method. What did you try to achieve with it?

Comment: is your request JS ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @roman-roman mentioned, you have your index and show views inside the reload page method...which I seriously doubt is what you intended to do.

You shouldn't have to call a method to get the page to reload on update. If you're submitting a form from the edit page to the update action the page will naturally reload after save.

Typical update action looks something like this:

```
@name_of_model = NameOfModel.find(params[:id])

respond_to do |format|
  if @name_of_model.update_attributes(name_of_model_params)
  # whatever the formats you want: but rendering html will include a    refresh
end
```

Get rid of reload page, take those methods out of reload_page and go from there. Just let the page reload.

If you need to reload bc you're using ajax to update...do it in the success or .done function in your javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need us to show the view related to that. A controller does not magically "fire" when a database record is changed, it only handles incoming requests from the browser. Do you have some javascript which periodically calls in?

Your defs should not be inside the `def reload_page`.

EDIT: also, you probably don't need to use some `after_filter` at all, just make a `is_update_necessary` action and call that like any other.